# SQL Server sysadmin user server role

Tags: sql-server, system-administration, rights-management

Is it possible to read/write into a SQL Server 2005 database, from a VB.NET application, using a user who does NOT have a sysadmin server role?

Comment: Yes. Of course. What would be the point of a security system if everyone had to be sysadmin?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, it would be much easier to use for one thing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from all tables in a database, there is a Database role called db_datareader. To insert/update/delete from all tables in a database, there is a Database role called db_datawriter.

The user will need to be mapped to a login at the Instance level, but no server roles will be required, especially not sysadmin.