# SQL Server: cannot login to database engine with new login without sysadmin server role

Tags: sql-server

Unfortunately I cannot find an answer to my problem.

I need a SQL Server login that allows to access, read, write/edit content of (a specific or several) database(s) and not more. So I created a new Login in SQL Server -> Security -> Logins. I have given all rights (User Mapping: db_datareader,db_datawriter - and also explicit permissions) that are needed for the purpose, but I cannot login to the server engine using SSMS and the created login with (yes) the correct password.

I already looked at the SQL Server logs which state:

> Login failed for user 'example'.
> Reason: Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks Connect SQL permission.
>
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 146

Needless to say I have also already granted Connect SQL Permission. I have also "login" enabled (in login settings). The server is in mixed authentication mode, connect rights given. Of course I can give server roles to this login (sysadmin) and suddenly I can login to the server engine, but, as said, I'm trying to adjust the permissions to my needs. Also restarted the server.

Already tried: [cannot login to sql server with new user created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676698/cannot-login-to-sql-server-with-new-user-created)
and: [SQL Server sysadmin user server role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599597/sql-server-sysadmin-user-server-role)

Other sources state to give sysadmin role, but this can't be the answer.

Has anyone ever come across this? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: The SQL Login has a default database setting - is that the same database that you've been applying all of the permissions to?

Comment: I've been applying the permission to SQL Login (through SQL Server -> Security -> Logins) and also to each database I'm using (through Database -> Security -> Users) @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Permissions are a separate thing to the actual login, though. If you're scripting it using [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql) then make sure the `DEFAULT_DATABASE` parameter matches the intended database. It defaults to `master` so an unprivileged user is going to have difficulties unless they specify the correct database in their connection string.

Comment: I think the error will be different if the default database is wrong. Make sure the login has the `CONNECT SQL` server permission and it's not denied, directly or indirectly, via server role membership(s). This will list direct grant/deny server permissions `SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals AS prin JOIN sys.server_permissions AS perm ON perm.grantee_principal_id = prin.principal_id;`
WHERE prin.name = 'test';

Comment: @DanGuzman on SQL 2005 and earlier it used to return 4064, I think, but SQL 2008 and later unhelpfully grouped a number of different conditions under 18456.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you may be right about the error number but the error text will be different, "cannot open database requested by the login". That can occur if the login doesn't have permissions, the db is offline, etc. But I don't think it's getting that far.

Comment: @DanGuzman I ran your query and it specifically says 'grant' for CONNECT SQL, only ALTER SERVER STATE and SHUTDOWN is on 'deny'
Also: I do have strings connecting to specific (correct) databases which also have the permissions configured for the login. So I'm clueless.

Comment: @JoeyR, check for server role memberships too as those might have a DENY. The denied permissions suggest someone has messed with defaults since only GRANT CONNECT SQL is granted when a new login is created and none are denied by default.

Comment: @DanGuzman okay, so seems like 'public' denies the sql connection, can I somehow remove public server role or should I change the server roles permissions?

Comment: @JoeyR, you should remove public role custom permissions. Only `VIEW ANY DATABASE` is granted with a default SQL installation but that does not confer access to user databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of SQL Server server-level permissions are:

1. SQL Server does not check permissions for sysadmin role members
2. GRANT and DENY permissions are cumulative (i.e. direct and via role memberships)
3. DENY takes precedence over GRANT of the same permission
4. All logins are a member of the built-in public role

[After creating a login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#after-creating-a-login), the login is implicitly granted CONNECT SQL and inherits only the limited (out-of-the-box) public role permissions.

Based on the info in your question and comments, the effect of the `DENY CONNECT SQL TO public;` is that only sysadmin role members can connect (per #1 above) and all other logins cannot connect (#2, #3, and #4).

It is generally a best practice to avoid DENY. There is never a need to DENY a permission that was not previously granted or inherited via role membership. DENY is used in specialized cases where one needs to negate a permission granted via role membership. A login will not have server-level permissions like ALTER SERVER STATE and SHUTDOWN unless it is explicitly granted to the login or role the login belongs to.

The example below will provision a login with access to a database and grant read/write permissions to a table.

```
CREATE LOGIN YourLogin WITH PASSWORD='<password-here>';
USE YourDatabase;
CREATE USER YourLogin;
GRANTT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE TO YourLogin;
```

Run the query below to identify permissions inadvertently granted or denied to the public server role and execute the REVOKE script to remove the permission. Only the default VIEW ANY DATABASE permissions will remain.

```
SELECT N'REVOKE ' + perm.permission_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + N' FROM ' + prin.name + N';' --, perm.state_desc, perm.permission_name
FROM sys.server_principals AS prin 
JOIN sys.server_permissions AS perm ON perm.grantee_principal_id = prin.principal_id 
WHERE 
    prin.name = 'public'
    AND perm.class_desc = 'Server'
    AND perm.permission_name <> 'VIEW ANY DATABASE';
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! This explains a lot I've come across while testing with roles and permissions. I have never edited the public role, as you mentioned I should remove the public role custom permissions, but I don't really know how to.

Comment: I've just double checked another database of mine that's running the same structure. There I can see that public does not deny connect sql. Does this mean I should re-install the sql server instance or is there a more simple way to do it?

Comment: @JoeyR, a re-install is a bit heavy handed. I added a script to identify non-default public role permissions. Run the revoke script to remediate the public server role permissions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I did re-install it and now it works like a charm. No idea how that server role hat custom permissions. I have not tried to use your method, so I can't say, but I believe it should be working, too.