# SQL Server 2019 Developer Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 149

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want my normal (role public) *user123* (SQL Auth, not PAD, not sysadmin) to login to SQL Server 2019 (Developer version).

- I have SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.
- I have protocols    in SQL Server Network Configuration enabled
  (TCP/IP, Local Machine,    Named Pipes).
- App connecting to DB is written in Visual Studio cpp, with SQLDriverConnect() function.

And I still get this error:

> Login failed for user 'user123'. Reason: Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks connect endpoint permission. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 149.

When I give *user123* sysadmin role, then he connects. But I don't want him to be sysadmin. In fact, I want two separate application to connect to the database with *user123* credentials as standard public user. But actually even one application can't connect.

There's a list of permissions:
[List of DB permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx3CM.png)

Any help and suggestions highly appreciated.

**SOLUTION FOUND:** Port in SQLDriverConnect() function shall be **1433** (default SQL instance) not 1434 (DAC Connection), with proper permission for public role on particular database (Connect, Select, Insert, etc.).

Comment: That image tells us nothing, but I see no "CONNECT SQL" permission.

Comment: Is `user123` a Windows Auth or SQL Auth login?

Comment: @Charlieface SQL Auth

Comment: @Larnu Do you mean "CONNECT SQL" for SERVER or ENDPOINT? For user123 or public? There is "CONNECT ANY DB" for user123 - is it some different kind/level of access?

Comment: Possible [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969294/sql-server-cannot-login-to-database-engine-with-new-login-without-sysadmin-serv/65973420?noredirect=1#comment116663953_65973420).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message and the screenshot, I suspect that you might be connecting to the DAC rather than to the main SQL instance.

Please recheck your connection string in the application - or test using SSSMS

Comment: _user123_ connects to DB via SSMS successfully.

Connection string in cpp: 

`SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=localhost, 1434; DATABASE=routingDB; UID=user123; PWD=pass123;", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)`

Comment: Ok, I think your suggestions put me on the right track - I had used port 1434 which is for DAC connection. Switching to 1433 seems to solve the problem, but it requires additional permissions in particular database (Connect, Select, Insert, etc. for public).

Comment: Correct - 1434 is the DAC and needs sysadmin membership.